# How do you play a SharePoint hosted video in an Excel spreadsheet

Tags: excel, vba, sharepoint

In my Excel file I want to create a form that plays a specific video when a command button is clicked. I have something that works now when the video is local on my computer but I can't get it to work for a video hosted on our company's SharePoint site. I get the form but nothing plays. (Even when I click the play button on the control.)

As I am thinking this through I'm guessing I need to create an object to serve as a connection to our SharePoint site, and somehow go through that connection but I have no idea what that would look like. Any suggestions?

First here is the working code that runs on the form's Initialize event;

```
With wmvHelpVideo
    .Url = "C:\Temp\MyVideo.mp4"
    .Controls.Play
    .stretchToFit = True
End With
```

And here was my attempt with SharePoint;

```
With wmvHelpVideo
    .Url = "https:\\MySite.sharepoint.com/sites/resources/Project%20Training%20Videos/Project%20Training%20Video.mov"
    .Controls.Play
    .stretchToFit = True
End With
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in your url.  "https:\" should be "https://"